# Неправильный перевод подсказки влияния

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, страница-учётной-записи

Оригинальный текст выглядит следующим образом:

> Estimated number of times people viewed your helpful posts (based on
>   page views of your questions and questions where you wrote
>   highly-ranked answers)

У нас выглядит так:

> Примерное число раз, сколько посетители сочли ваши  сообщения
>   полезными (польза определяется количеством просмотров ваших вопросов и
>   ваших ответов с высоким рейтингом)

Очевидно, что это неверный перевод.

---

Есть ещё такая строка:

> Estimated number of times people viewed helpful posts by this user
>   (based on page views of questions
>   and questions where they wrote highly-ranked answers)

Comment: Согласен, о выражении мнения речь не идёт.

Comment: Здесь неплохо бы знать, «highly-ranked» — это сколько? Предполагаю, что просто выше нуля.

Comment: [We're working on a new stat to help convey the reach of your posts here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534)

Answer (score 2):

А должно быть так:

> Примерное число раз, когда посетители видели ваши полезные сообщения
>   (польза определяется количеством просмотров ваших вопросов и
>   вопросов, на которые вы ответили, получив высокий рейтинг)

Comment: Тут есть ошибка: не польза сообщений определяется количеством просмотров, а суммарное число просмотров. А для пользы есть свои критерии.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я перевёл с английского. Если пройтись по Meta SE, то можно встретить очень разные, взаимоисключающие определения для влияния. Это вообще уже похоже больше на бред.

Comment: в английском тексте не говорится, что польза определяется просмотрами. Там вообще нет слова «польза».

Comment: @NickVolynkin, а как вы слово "helpful" переводите?

Comment: "helpful posts" = «полезные сообщения», но не «польза».

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [посту на Мете SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/244534/296059), для вопросов и для ответов есть строгие критерии, при выполнении которых те и другие добавляют свои просмотры к показателю «влияния» конкретного участника. <s>Показатель считается просто как сумма, так что можно не вносить дополнительной путаницы и писать прямо и конкретно.</s>

> Примерное число раз, когда посетители видели ваши полезные сообщения (считается на основе просмотров ваших вопросов и просмотров вопросов, на которые вы дали высоко оцененные ответы)
>
> Примерное число раз, когда посетители видели полезные сообщения этого участника (считается на основе просмотров ваших вопросов и просмотров вопросов, на которые участник дал высоко оцененные ответы)

«Высоко оцененные» это как раз одно из:

- Принят автором вопроса
- Один из трех лучших ответов
- Более 5 рейтинга

Comment: Я вижу проблему со словом "сумма": это привязка к текущей реализации, которая может измениться в будущем. Сегодня может быть сумма, завтра будет произведение. :)

Comment: @Discord: ок, отвяжем от реализации.

Comment: А почему бы не сказать "на основе просмотров ваших вопросов и высоко оценённых ответов"? Будет проще читать. Ведь если просмотрели вопрос, то просмотрели и ответы к нему

Comment: @TimofeyBondarev: меня смущает, что это вроде бы неточно, но нравится, что гораздо лаконичнее.

Answer (score 0):

Воспользовался идеей Timofey Bondarev:

> Примерное число раз, когда посетители видели ваши полезные сообщения (считается на основе просмотров ваших вопросов и высоко оцененных ответов)
>
> Примерное число раз, когда посетители видели полезные сообщения этого участника (считается на основе просмотров вопросов и высоко оцененных ответов участника)

Применил этот вариант.